# How to Properly Name Kubernetes Resources Deployed using Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, aws-cdk

I'm deploying some charts (e.g. Nginx Ingress) using Helm, but the generated name is just too long. Is it possible to set a proper name for the DaemonSet, default backend service, etc?
For the record I'm using CDK to install the chart:

```js
cluster.addChart('NginxIngress', {
  chart: 'nginx-ingress',
  repository: 'https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com',
  namespace: 'ingress-nginx',
  wait: true,
  values: {
    controller: {
      kind: 'DaemonSet',
      hostNetwork: true,
      daemonset: {
        useHostPort: true,
      },
      service: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://technosophos.github.io/common-chart/), there's two properties that control the naming: `nameOverride` and `fullnameOverride`. Depending on the requirement either one can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the chart name use "nameOverride" and to completely replace the name generated for the resource use "fullnameOverride" like:

`name: {{ include "<CHARTNAME>.fullname" . }}`

```
values: {
   fullnameOverride: '<custom-name>',
}
```

`name: {{ include "<CHARTNAME>.name" . }}`

```
values: {
   nameOverride: '<custom-name>',
}
```